# Bezier handles (tangents) on spiral addon

Tags: bezier-curves

I've added a spiral, using the spiral addon. It doesn't have bezier handles, nor does it behave like a Nurbs Curve, what can I do about that?

I want to curve the edge of the selected vertex, but I don't know how.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depending on which type of spiral you are creating there are some spline options often only 'POLY' or 'NURBS'.

However in EDIT mode on the tools panel you can change the spline type.

[image]

Comment: Tyvm, exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know about polygon type curves!